# Is the script gltfjsx used to turn glt files into usable jsx safe?

Tags: reactjs, gltf, gltools

Is using npx gltfsx safe?

gltfsx is "a small command-line tool that turns GLTF assets into declarative and re-usable react-three-fiber JSX components".

Link to github: https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx

Comment: Yes (in a word)

Answer (score 0):

Low quality question, that makes no sense overall, check the "Used By" section on the github page or check how many stars it has, then check the projects that use it, if they seem legit then yes?